# SyntaxError: Strict mode ... after initialising project

Tags: react-native

I am evaluating react for my development purposes. Just now, trying to initialise a project (which has worked perfectly until yesterday) the following error occurs

```
SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement. (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:24821)
```

after

```
react-native init SomeProject
```

Comment: Got the same error, but debug mode works. So temporary solution might be to work with debug mode only...'

Comment: did this work for you before, as it did with me? I was able to build these projects the same way a day before. No changes on my configuration in between. Makes me seriously reconsider using react native.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement on a newly created app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058495/syntaxerror-strict-mode-does-not-allow-function-declarations-in-a-lexically-nes)

Answer (score 1):

see my answer here [SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement on a newly created app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058495/syntaxerror-strict-mode-does-not-allow-function-declarations-in-a-lexically-nes/41059867#41059867)

there is simple workaround for this and I think it will be fixed soon in react-native

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error and previously it was working fine. It seems like there is an issue with React Native 0.39.0 as reported [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11384) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11389).

To solve this issue, try reverting the React Native version back to '0.38.0' by running `npm uninstall react-native` then `npm install react-native@0.38.0` in your project folder.