# SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement on a newly created app

Tags: react-native

I got this error today, then I uninstall react-native-cli and reinstall it, the problem's still there. I even run the reset-cache command! I tried to create a new react-native app and still see the error.
I don't want to reinstall my os for this...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I've faced this issue too
this happened because babel now adds 'use strict' automatically
so it checks function declarations in a lexically nested statement

this happens in core react-native code (node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\src\androidTest\assets\AndroidTestBundle.js)
you can find more info in github issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11389

as a workaround you can enable remote debugging - it works for me

I've found simple solution

> open node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\InitializeCore.js line 112
>
> change function handleError(e, isFatal) to var handleError = function(e, isFatal)
>
> then do npm start -- --reset-cache

you can also check it in github issue above

Comment: Work around works. Just edit the file and change the function declaration.

Comment: Upgrade to 0.40.0 to fix the issue

Comment: There is no 'Core' under 'node_modules\react-native\Libraries'

Comment: @Zip which version of react are you on?

Comment: I can't also find 'Core' as @Zip. react version = 15.3.1, react native version = 0.34

Comment: It is found in node_modules\react-native\Libraries\JavaScriptAppEngine\Initialization\InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js

Comment: @chazefate that's correct. Making the code change to that file does not solve this issue, however. Either the problem is in some other file as well or something else entirely causes this issue. RN@0.34.1

Comment: It doesn't works for me. The file was at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/JavaScriptAppEngine/Initialization/InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js different direcotry as mentioned in above answer.  react native version 0.27.2 and react 15.1.0

Answer (score 8):

For those who can't find the Core folder in the the react-native node_modules. You might be running a different version like I was, and found it here:

> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\JavaScriptAppEngine\Initialization\InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js
>
> line ~120

and change

```
function handleError(e, isFatal)
```

to

```
var handleError = function(e, isFatal)
```

then do `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Answer (score 3):

Just activate a JS Minify option in the Emulator Dev Settings

> In Emulator: Menu > Dev Settings > JS Minify ☑(active)

Here it worked only with this, I hope it has helped;)

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem by using "rninit rn4web --source react-native@0.31.0"， and then exec "react-native run-android".

the solution for me is "Menu -> Dev Setting -> JS Minify(active it)".

Here it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change `function handleError(e, isFatal) to var handleError = function(e, isFatal)` at line 112 in path

```
node_modules\react-native\Libraries\JavaScriptAppEngine\Init‌​ialization\Initializ‌​eJavaScriptAppEngine‌​.js
```

then do `npm start -- --reset-cache`