# React-Native: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement.

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

Tried running this app: https://github.com/VctrySam/Twitter
on Android (Real Device) and it shows this error:
[Android Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTdSJ.png)

- I have the latest React Native Cli and Node.js version 6.9.5 (Windows
  x64)
- The app has React-Native `^0.32.1` written in the dependencies.

So on Stack Overflow, I tried a modification to the React source which doesn't change the error.
[SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement on a newly created app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058495/syntaxerror-strict-mode-does-not-allow-function-declarations-in-a-lexically-nes)

How would I go about running this app?

Comment: Upgrade your React Native version!

Comment: That's a pretty old version of React Native. I would suggest creating a new project, copying over the app folder, and installing the dependencies, then starting the app. This should work.